# Add headers to QGIS symbology and add colour ramp

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend

I have added a catagorical symbology based on a simple filter in QGIS Desktop 3.6.3.
I have three different columns on which the coloring of features should be based. Combinations of column values are possible and not all columns have data.

The symbology is based on the following expression, I am content with the output:

```
CASE
    
    WHEN Veg_codom <> '' AND  Veg_onderg <> '' THEN Veg_dom + '+' +         Veg_codom 
    WHEN  Veg_codom IS NULL AND  Veg_onderg <> '' THEN Veg_dom
    WHEN Veg_codom <> '' AND  Veg_onderg IS NULL THEN Veg_dom + '+' +       Veg_codom
    WHEN Veg_codom IS NULL AND Veg_onderg IS NULL THEN Veg_dom
    
END
```

The layout now looks like this:
[image]

I am struggeling for a while now to produce the following, but no succes:

[image]

So: I want to add headers to my symbology (that also translate to my legend for print-composer) and I want to be able to control colour ramps for each group. In Arcmap this is fairly easy to do and this is actually the first thing I find harder to find out on QGIS.

Atrribute table is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Have you looked into "rule based symbology" ? 
Otherwise, if you have the other layer and its symbology in QGIS you could copy all the symbology and paste it to your new layer.

As far as I know it is not possible to use a color ramp for categorical data?

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the response. I can add a colour ramp to my symbology now, but this automatically applies to the whole set. So, i want to omit this by subsetting/nesting my initial symbology within headers. I have tried the rule based symbology, but achieved no result with this. The categories do give the result I want, but i cant seem to add headers.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you further as I am not sure myself. Maybe someone else can add? I am curious for the solution/